# Setting cookies in ASP with "_" in the cookies name

Tags: cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

We have two application, One is in ASP.net(lets call it A) and another is in classic asp(B) which is out in house APP. Now when we login in A, we are setting one cookies called "site_abc" which is coming from our single signon. Everything works well with this cookies and our other applications. But the issue is when we are setting the same cookie in our classic ASP application its read as "site%5Fabc" and now we have two cookies.

```
site_abc and site%5Fabc
```

The why cookies are set in Application B is as below

```
Response.Cookies("site_abc") = "somevalue"
```

What i was hoping for was when i set cookies in B, it would replcae the value set by A in the "site_abc" bu its creates a new cookie "site%5Fabc". Any help would be helpful.

Comment: You can always set a cookie manually via `Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "xxx"` and this should output the data as its written.